# What modifications are possible\necessary when transferring Tridion schemas between development environments

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I would like to maintain my Tridion schema definitions in an external management system (in this case, GIT). To do this I am accessing the Tridion content manager via webdav. When I do so, in general, the links to other system items are transformed to webdav urls.

When I have a reference to a category, this becomes more difficult, as the namespace URI includes an embedded reference to the publication. Here is an extract from the webdav view of one of my schemas:

```
<xsd:import namespace="tcm:0-3-1/Categories.xsd" 
            schemaLocation="/webdav/01%20Definitions/Categories.xsd"/>
```

If the publication IDs are different between system, this will be a problem. My first thought was that seeing as namespace URIs are in principle opaque, I could just replace it with my own system-neutral value. Unfortunately, it appears that the content manager parses the namespace URI to determine the schema location, and if it doesn't recognise the first part of the string as a URI the save fails.

Is there a way of achieving my goal by editing the schema in some other way? Are there any alternative approaches?

Comment: Is this approach to avoid using Content Porter?  On this note, how do you suppose CP works around this?

Comment: In some development scenarios content porter isn't as good a fit as I'd like. However, I definitely see its place in deployments beyond the development team. Content Porter runs its own service, so doesn't rely on the webdav implementation.

Comment: May I ask why you want to maintain your schema's externally? Is this to create an "external" backup of Tridion? Or is it purely for reference purposes?

Comment: Is there any way to change this namespace from an event handler when the Schema is saved? You could verify the publication ID in the namespace with the Publication in which it is tried to be created.

Comment: Hi Dominic, did you ever made progress in this?

Comment: Hi Arjen, To be honest, I abandoned this approach, as basically, it's only useful if it's easier than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do anything with client side GIT hook scripts, but otherwise an event handler might be able to do something. When you try to Save a Schema you could match the publication I'd with the owning publication.

Not a direct answer, but a suggestion. Maybe it brings you further.